# Why I am getting the following error in using Lasso from sklearn.linear_model?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to run Lasso on a dataset with part of the set being a validating set.
Below are the dimensions of the sets:

```
train_X_tfidf.shape  (15361, 1500)
train_y.shape        (15361, 3)
val_X_tfidf.shape    (10241, 1500)
val_y.shape          (10241, 3)
```

Below is the code snippet that is throwing an error:

```
from sklearn import linear_model 
ols_lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
ols_lasso.fit(train_X_tfidf,train_y)
Lasso_pred = ols_lasso.predict(val_X_tfidf)
```

Below is the traceback of the error that I am getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-344-e823b20eba99> in <module>()
     14 ols_lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
     15 ols_lasso.fit(train_X_tfidf,train_y)
---> 16 Lasso_pred = ols_lasso.predict(val_X_tfidf)
     17 #LR_pred
     18 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    149 
    150         Returns
--> 151         -------
    152         C : array, shape = (n_samples,)
    153             Returns predicted values.

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.pyc in decision_function(self, X)
    732         and you should prefer the LinearRegression object.
    733 
--> 734     fit_intercept : boolean
    735         whether to calculate the intercept for this model. If set
    736         to false, no intercept will be used in calculations

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,10241) (3,)
```

Can anybody point out what is wrong with the code ?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** 
I have tried the following :

1. I generated random data with the same dimensions as my original data and then tried lasso. **No problem**, It ran fine.
2. I have used the lasso.fit(train_X_tfidf,train_y) and then generated a **random sparse matrix** of dimension equal to that of my `val_X_tfidf` sparse matrix and ran predict function on the new val data. I didn't encounter any problem.
3. On this exact data, I ran `LinearRegression` from `sklearn.linear_model` and that worked fine.

So I am  not sure why I am getting the above mentioned `ValueError:`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is weird, the traceback points to the wrong lines (docstring instead of code lines). Maybe you could uninstall and reinstall scikit-learn?

Comment: Also could you please provide a self-contained snippet that reproduces the issue (e.g. with randomly generated data)?

Comment: I actually updated sklearn and the re-ran it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @ogrisel....I tried to run this code snippet on a randomly generated small toy example with multiple targets columns. It runs fine. No problem...I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

As it's indicated in the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.fit):

> fit(X, y): Fit model with coordinate descent.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - nX : ndarray or scipy.sparse matrix, (n_samples, n_features): Data
> - y : ndarray, shape = (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_targets): Target

Let's take a look to your code:

```
ols_lasso.fit(train_X_tfidf,train_y)

#val_y.shape          (10241, 3) >> this should be with shape (10241,)
#train_X_tfidf.shape  (15361, 1500)
```

Comment: @Farhini, thanks for your comments...but **val_y** doesn't enter into picture (as my code snippet shows) until you calculate the error of the predicted target values...Please note that the train_y's dimension is `(15361, 3)` so that should be good and note that multiple targets are allowed as shown in the documentation..not just single target...

Answer (score 0):

As we saw above int he traceback of the error, `decision_function(val_X_tfidf)` was throwing the value error.`val_X_tfidf` is sparse matrix. When I ran `decision_function(val_X_tfidf.todense())`, it ran fine. In fact, when I ran lasso (the code snippet int he question ) with sparse_matrix converted to matrix via `to dense()` function, it ran and produced no value error.

Although, I must mention that when I ran Lasso using a randomly generated set of numbers having the same dimension as my original sets, it ran fine. So even now, I don't have a clue as to what is wrong here.

However, for the time being, I will convert it into a `numpy ndarry` so that I can finish my project.

SO IF ANYBODY CAN FIND OUT WHAT IS WRONG ABOVE, PLEASE LEAVE YOUR THOUGHTS HERE. THANKS.